# Laravel Modal de Confirmación despues de hacer un post

Tags: html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy trabajando con laravel y plantillas de Blade. 
He creado un metodo para cargar archivos a mi base de datos, este es el método en mi controlador:

```
       public function import (Request $request)
{
    $filename =  $request->file('select_file')->getRealPath();

    $file =fopen($filename, "r");

    while(!feof($file)){
        $content =fgets($file);
        $carray=explode("|", $content);
        list ($cliente,$moneda,$tipo_transaccion,$razon_transaccion,$monto_pago,$fecha_pago,$narrativo,$cuenta,$es_core)=$carray;

        $query = DB::insert('insert into `pagos` (`cliente`,`moneda`,`tipoTransaccion`,`razonTransaccion`,`montoPago`,`fecha_pago`,`narrativo`,`cuenta`,`esCore`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
            [$cliente,$moneda,$tipo_transaccion,$razon_transaccion,$monto_pago,$fecha_pago,$narrativo,$cuenta,$es_core]);
        }

        fclose($file);  
    }
```

Y este es mi formulario

```
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('/carga/pagos/import') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group">
 <table class="table">
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" align="right"><label>Seleccione Archivo</label></td>
   <td width="30">
    <input type="file" name="select_file"  accept=".txt". required="true" />
   </td>
   <td width="30%" align="left">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cargar Información">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" align="right"></td>
   <td width="30"><span class="text-muted">El arhivo debe ser formato txt</span></td>
   <td width="30%" align="left"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Esto me funciona bien, pero ahora quiero implementar un modal de confirmación una vez el post se haya ejecutado con exito.

Como podría implementar ese modal en mi código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes implementar el uso de una variable de session que pasara el controlador una vez ejecutado correctamente el metodo que llamo el formulario en con el atributo action del formulario, luego este se lee en el formulario al ser retornado y tomando el valor de la  variable session.

Este es el ejemplo:

**Para el formulario debe poner el codigo siguiente:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('/carga/pagos/import') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group">
 <table class="table">
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" align="right"><label>Seleccione Archivo</label></td>
   <td width="30">
    <input type="file" name="select_file"  accept=".txt". required="true" />
   </td>
   <td width="30%" align="left">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cargar Información">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="40%" align="right"></td>
   <td width="30"><span class="text-muted">El arhivo debe ser formato txt</span></td>
   <td width="30%" align="left"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>

  @if (session('report'))
               <h1>{{ session('report') }}</h1>
  @endif
```

Donde:

`@if (session('report'))` es el helper blade que pregunta si existe la variable session "report" al ser verdad ejecuta su contenido que es  `<h1>{{ session('report') }}</h1>`

**Del lado del controlador debes colocar lo siguiente:**

```
 public function import (Request $request)
{
    $filename =  $request->file('select_file')->getRealPath();

    $file =fopen($filename, "r");

    while(!feof($file)){
        $content =fgets($file);
        $carray=explode("|", $content);
        list ($cliente,$moneda,$tipo_transaccion,$razon_transaccion,$monto_pago,$fecha_pago,$narrativo,$cuenta,$es_core)=$carray;

        $query = DB::insert('insert into `pagos` (`cliente`,`moneda`,`tipoTransaccion`,`razonTransaccion`,`montoPago`,`fecha_pago`,`narrativo`,`cuenta`,`esCore`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
            [$cliente,$moneda,$tipo_transaccion,$razon_transaccion,$monto_pago,$fecha_pago,$narrativo,$cuenta,$es_core]);
        }

        fclose($file);  

         $request->session()->flash('notificacion', 'Archivo guardado');
         return back();
    }
```

Donde:

```
$request->session()->flash('report', 'Archivo guardado');
```

Crea la variable de session llamada report con el contenido "Archivo guardado"

```
return back();
```

regresa a la ruta donde fue llamado el controlador

Comment: Mil gracias... funcionó perfecto